# Firebase functions: Listen to all delete changes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a database like this:

```
- users
    - userId1
        - activities
            - football: "20€"
        - competitions
            - competitionId1
                - football
                    - prize: "40€"

    - userId2
        - activities
            - baskets: "20€"
            - football: "30€"
        - competitions
            - competitionId4
                - basket
                    - prize: "40€"
```

So I would like to be notified on all deletes on this, I tried to use

```js
functions.database.ref("users/{userId}").onDelete();
```

But it only listens to `users/{userId}`, I could use `.onUpdate()`, but I really need to know the entire path of the deleted object.

The only thing I could try to do is using `.onUpdate()` and doing a deep comparison between the old and the new value to retrieve what element got removed.

But I don't think it's the best solution

For example:

If I remove `users/userId1/competitions`

I will be notified that `users/userId1/competitions` is removed

Comment: Can you clarify, in your database structure, what is a Document, a Field in a Document, a Subcollection and a Document in the Subcollection. For example, it is not clear if activities is a subcollection or a field of type Array. Also what do you mean by "I would like to be notified on all deletes on this". Deletion of which elements in this structure?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec It's a realtime database there is no document, collection it's just like a json file

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I indeed mixed up the two database services! :-) see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_instance_and_path) in the doc for Cloud Functions triggered by Realtime Database events.

> Path specifications match all writes that touch a path, including
> writes that happen anywhere below it.
>
> ...
>
> **If the event data might be large, consider using multiple functions at
> deeper paths instead of a single function near the root** of your
> database. For the best performance, only request data at the deepest
> level possible.

It's really up to you to decide if you should defined several Cloud Functions. However, **since you want to listen to deletions**, it will be probably easier to write a Cloud Function for each level, like:

```
functions.database.ref("users/{userId}").onDelete(...);

functions.database.ref("users/{userId}/{activitiesOrCompetitions}").onDelete(...);

functions.database.ref("users/{userId}/{activitiesOrCompetitions}/{CompetitionId}").onDelete(...);
```

Note that each time you'll delete a `CompetitionId` node, if there is no more `competitions` for this user, you'll trigger the second Cloud Function above.

Again, it's up to you to decide if you want to trigger several Cloud Functions for one deletion or you prefer to trigger only one Cloud Function (with `onUpdate()`) and compare the snapshots, as you mentioned in your question. Remember that there is a generous free tier for Cloud Functions executions of 2M/month.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the listener to:

```js
functions.database.ref("users/{userId}/{path}").onDelete();
```

Then `path` in your `context` would be either "activities", "competitions" etc..

Comment: If I do this, It doesn't listen to the subpath for example: users/userId2/activities/football

Comment: Can you add also the subpath?